# How to do data alignment in C?

Tags: c, macros, alignment, memory-alignment

I want to know why the following macro works for data alignment in C? 
`#define CMIALIGN(x,n)       (size_t)((~(n-1))&((x)+(n-1)))` Say if n is equal to 7 why the following macro should work? `#define ALIGN8(x)        (size_t)((~7)&((x)+7)` . Can you please show it with some example and tell why this formula works? Is there any other tangible formula for data alignment?

Comment: Have you drawn the bits on a piece of paper and see what each step does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of the `~N` (where N is one less than the alignment you seek), is to ensure all high-order bits already present in your number are *kept* lit after the alignment, including the bits pushed there by the add operation. The actual round-up for alignment is done by the addition of `N` This ensures that any proper carry-bits are pushed into higher bits locations, which the bitwise-AND with `~N` is then guaranteed to retain while ensuring the bottom bits are swept away, as they are not needed.

Imagine this:

```
   00100011 :  35
+  00000111 :   7
   --------   ----
   00101010 :  42
&  11111000 :  ~7
   ---------- ----
   00101000 :  40
```

Another example:

```
  11101111 : 239
+ 00000111 :   7
  --------   ----
  11110110 : 246
& 11111000 :  ~7
  --------   ----
  11110000 : 240
```

And finally, an example that ends up doing nothing, as it is already aligned:

```
  10100000 : 160
+ 00000111 :   7
  --------   ----
  10100111 : 167
& 11111000 :  ~7
  --------   ----
  10100000 : 160
```

I should note that this offers no real protection against overflow, other than the caller side checking for a zero-return value, which would clearly be not what you would want to use as a rounded-up alignment value.

```
  11111110 : 254
+ 00000111 :   7
  --------   ----
  00000101 :   5  (of)
& 11111000 :  ~7
  --------   ----
  00000000 :   0
```